# Error when checking checkbox property

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, syntax-error

I want to show `div` if checkbox is checked. If not, I want to hide it. Here is my code, but it doesn't work.

```
$(".formularz_zgloszeniowy .firma input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(".formularz_zgloszeniowy .formularz_firma").css('display'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,'block');​​​​​​
    } 
    else 
    {
      $(".formularz_zgloszeniowy .formularz_firma").css('display'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,'none');​​​​​​
    }
});
```

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

EDIT:
Here is full code in `head` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$(".formularz_zgloszeniowy .firma input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".formularz_zgloszeniowy .formularz_firma").css('display'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,'block');​​​​​​
    } 
    else 
    {
      $(".formularz_zgloszeniowy .formularz_firma").css('display'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,'none');​​​​​​
    }
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: just use : if($(this).is(":checked"))

Comment: Can you post a fiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: That code should not throw such error. The culprit must be something else.

Comment: There's a ton of [non-printable characters](http://jsfiddle.net/s5b9yo7h/) in the example, probably in your real code too?

Comment: @DinoMyte That's just less efficient.

Comment: @DinoMyte doesn't work. I have added full code from head tag to question.

Comment: @gkopowski Just check the fiddle I've linked. You see the red dots? They are `\u200b` characters breaking your code.

Comment: @Teemu Unfortunately people here think that the code doesn't work as it's not "enough jQuery" :)

Comment: @Teemu that was the problem! thank You! But its strange because I've checked these dots in Notepad++ and Sublime Text and none of these showed it. Only in jsfiddle appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some invisible characters in your code that are causing the problem. Here is your code working perfectly without those characters:

```js
$(".formularz_zgloszeniowy .firma input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  if(this.checked) {
    $(".formularz_zgloszeniowy .formularz_firma").css('display','block');
  } 
  else {
    $(".formularz_zgloszeniowy .formularz_firma").css('display','none');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formularz_zgloszeniowy">
  <div class="firma">
    <input type="checkbox" value="test" /> Test checkbox
  </div>
  <div class="formularz_firma">Test div</div>
</div>
```

And here is the code copied from your question with those invisible characters, so it is not working:

```js
$(".formularz_zgloszeniowy .firma input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(".formularz_zgloszeniowy .formularz_firma").css('display'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,'block');​​​​​​
    } 
    else 
    {
      $(".formularz_zgloszeniowy .formularz_firma").css('display'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,'none');​​​​​​
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formularz_zgloszeniowy">
  <div class="firma">
    <input type="checkbox" value="test" /> Test checkbox
  </div>
  <div class="formularz_firma">Test div</div>
</div>
```